# nginx load balancer cannot send "proxy_host" value correctly

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, load-balancing

I want to use nginx load balancer. The domain servers used in the upstream section use a shared IP.
Suppose the domain name of the load balancer server is `load-balancer.com`

```
upstream test_upstream {
      server upstream1.com;
      server upstream2.com;
}
```

and

```
location / {

              proxy_redirect off;
              proxy_http_version 1.1;
              proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
              proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

              proxy_pass http://test_upstream/;
              proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
          }
```

Because the domains use a shared IP, it is very important that the `Host` value is equal to `upstream1.com` or `upstream2.com`. But `$proxy_host` sets the `Host` value equal to the upstream name. (In this example, it sets `test_upstream` in Host).
The header received in the upstream server is as follows:

```
065.227.015.247.39136-085.083.104.010.00080: GET / HTTP/1.1
Connection: upgrade
Host: test_upstream
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/98.0.0.0
....
```

Also, using `$host` or `$http_host` instead of `$proxy_host` will also send the value of `load-balancer.com` as Host.
Also, if `$upstream_http_host` or `$upstream_http_server` or `$upstream_http_addr` is used, a 404 error will occur.
How to set the Host value correctly?

Comment: If the upstream server share the same IP, what's the point in the load balancer in the first place?

Comment: @gerald-schneider It is used in an anti-censorship method of the Internet